# Реализация бинарной матрицы

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Есть массив с базы данных

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [uID] => 31
        [uGroup] =>
        [uLogin] => admin1@gmail.com
        [uPass] => 52573ab13b0e0d834f530d0f4c21ee13
        [uPass2] =>
        [uMail] => admin1@gmail.com
        [ulogo] => karta-dgerela.jpg
        [uPIN] => 9f6e688b1037dd20d57937de0b867e1e
        [uState] => 1
        [uBTS] =>
        [uLevel] => 1
        [uLang] => ru
        [uMode] =>
        [uTheme] =>
        [uRef] => 1
        [uBal] => 0.000000
        [uLTS] => 0
        [uLIP] => 127.0.0.1
        [uLSess] => 63a9126942f88b1369f269591f6a634a
        [uPTS] => 0
        [uBFC] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [uID] => 36
        [uGroup] =>
        [uLogin] => admin1@gmail.com1
        [uPass] => 52573ab13b0e0d834f530d0f4c21ee13
        [uPass2] =>
        [uMail] => admin1@gmail.com1
        [ulogo] => karta-dgerela.jpg
        [uPIN] => 9f6e688b1037dd20d57937de0b867e1e
        [uState] => 1
        [uBTS] =>
        [uLevel] => 1
        [uLang] => ru
        [uMode] =>
        [uTheme] =>
        [uRef] => 1
        [uBal] => 0.000000
        [uLTS] => 0
        [uLIP] => 127.0.0.1
        [uLSess] => 63a9126942f88b1369f269591f6a634a
        [uPTS] => 0
        [uBFC] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [uID] => 37
        [uGroup] =>
        [uLogin] => admin1@gmail.com2
        [uPass] => 52573ab13b0e0d834f530d0f4c21ee13
        [uPass2] =>
        [uMail] => admin1@gmail.com2
        [ulogo] => karta-dgerela.jpg
        [uPIN] => 9f6e688b1037dd20d57937de0b867e1e
        [uState] => 1
        [uBTS] =>
        [uLevel] => 1
        [uLang] => ru
        [uMode] =>
        [uTheme] =>
        [uRef] => 1
        [uBal] => 0.000000
        [uLTS] => 0
        [uLIP] => 127.0.0.1
        [uLSess] => 63a9126942f88b1369f269591f6a634a
        [uPTS] => 0
        [uBFC] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [uID] => 38
        [uGroup] =>
        [uLogin] => admin1@gmail.com3
        [uPass] => 52573ab13b0e0d834f530d0f4c21ee13
        [uPass2] =>
        [uMail] => admin1@gmail.com3
        [ulogo] => karta-dgerela.jpg
        [uPIN] => 9f6e688b1037dd20d57937de0b867e1e
        [uState] => 1
        [uBTS] =>
        [uLevel] => 1
        [uLang] => ru
        [uMode] =>
        [uTheme] =>
        [uRef] => 1
        [uBal] => 0.000000
        [uLTS] => 0
        [uLIP] => 127.0.0.1
        [uLSess] => 63a9126942f88b1369f269591f6a634a
        [uPTS] => 0
        [uBFC] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [uID] => 39
        [uGroup] =>
        [uLogin] => admin1@gmail.com4
        [uPass] => 52573ab13b0e0d834f530d0f4c21ee13
        [uPass2] =>
        [uMail] => admin1@gmail.com4
        [ulogo] => karta-dgerela.jpg
        [uPIN] => 9f6e688b1037dd20d57937de0b867e1e
        [uState] => 1
        [uBTS] =>
        [uLevel] => 1
        [uLang] => ru
        [uMode] =>
        [uTheme] =>
        [uRef] => 1
        [uBal] => 0.000000
        [uLTS] => 0
        [uLIP] => 127.0.0.1
        [uLSess] => 63a9126942f88b1369f269591f6a634a
        [uPTS] => 0
        [uBFC] => 0
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [uID] => 40
        [uGroup] =>
        [uLogin] => admin1@gmail.com5
        [uPass] => 52573ab13b0e0d834f530d0f4c21ee13
        [uPass2] =>
        [uMail] => admin1@gmail.com5
        [ulogo] => karta-dgerela.jpg
        [uPIN] => 9f6e688b1037dd20d57937de0b867e1e
        [uState] => 1
        [uBTS] =>
        [uLevel] => 1
        [uLang] => ru
        [uMode] =>
        [uTheme] =>
        [uRef] => 1
        [uBal] => 0.000000
        [uLTS] => 0
        [uLIP] => 127.0.0.1
        [uLSess] => 63a9126942f88b1369f269591f6a634a
        [uPTS] => 0
        [uBFC] => 0
    )

)
```

Нужно реализовать бинарную матрицу вот такого вида [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отобразить её. У меня выходит что высота матрицы 5 уровней, один человек всех приглашает, но они становятся все по два человека (как на картинке)

Comment: да, или один. Но родитель у них, тот кто во главе пирамиды

Comment: А где код? С чем помогать то?